# Unexpected Output plus segmentation error with my C program

Tags: c

I am trying to learn programming and was trying the following code in C. However, As you can see below I am not getting the expected output and I am getting a segmentation error while trying out solutions :

I feel I am doing something wrong with the declaration of First name or something. But not able to figure it out.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char first_name;
    printf("Enter your name: \n");
    scanf("%c", &first_name);
    printf("Hello, %c", first_name);
}
```

Actual Output

This is the output I am currently getting:

```
Enter your name: 
asdasfasf
Hello, a
```

Expected Output

```
Enter your name: 
asdasfasf
Hello, asdasfasf
```

Comment: You are only reading and printing a single `char`, why would you expect it to read an entire string?

Comment: char is a single character. A string is an array of chars ending with '\0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){    
        char first_name[100] = {0}; 
        printf("Enter your name:(Max length is 99)\n"); 
        scanf("%99s", first_name); 
        printf("Hello, %s\n", first_name); 
}
```

Run it will output

```
Enter your name:(Max length is 99)
asdasfasf
Hello, asdasfasf
```

Here is my other solution that can handle @Andreas Wenzel point out that "it is possible for a first name to consist of several words":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char first_name[100] = {0};
    char c = 0;
    printf("Enter your name:(Max length is 99)\n");

    // read 99 times, once a character, it suspend when read '\n', 
    // otherwise save to first_name array  when read character.
    for(int m = 0; m < 99; m++){
        if((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
            first_name[m] = c;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Hello, %s\n", first_name);
}
```

Run it will output

```
Enter your name:(Max length is 99)
asdsfd  
Hello, asdsfd
```

or like this:

```
Enter your name:(Max length is 99)
dsds dggffgg
Hello, dsds dggffgg
```

or also like this:

```
Enter your name:(Max length is 99)
ssd dsdfds dsfdfgfdg ddfdsfdf sfsdfsdf
Hello, ssd dsdfds dsfdfgfdg ddfdsfdf sfsdfsdf
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Really very new to coding so thank you for answering this dumb question.

Comment: @Whozcry Upvotes are not possible with 1 reputation..

Comment: It may be worth noting that using the `%s` conversion format specifier with `scanf` will not work for first names that consist of several words, such as "John Paul". See my answer for a solution which can also handle that case. However, since this is a rare corner-case, I am still upvoting your answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel First thank you for you upvote my answer. My native language is not English. As far as I know, English names usually consist of two words with a space between them (there are also English names that consist of three words). The code in the question uses "first_name", which I think only prints one word. For example, if the name is "John Paul", only "John" should be printed.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Additionally, there seems to be an issue in your statement "first names that consist of several words, such as 'John Paul'", where the issue lies in the phrase "first names" implying that there can only be one word and not two. So I think your said first names may be like this: JohnPaul or John. Although the format of "JohnPaul" may not be entirely correct.

Comment: @Whozcry: You are correct that if someone's name is for example "John Michael Doe", then "John" is the first name, "Michael" is the middle name and "Doe" is the last name. In English, most first names consist of only a single word. However, there are exceptions, such as [John Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Paul_(given_name)). With the name "John Paul Doe", the first name would be "John Paul", there would be no middle name, and the last name would be "Doe".

Comment: @Whozcry: There are also non-English names in which the first name has spaces, i.e. it consists of several words. See [this link](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78746/how-to-get-others-to-understand-that-my-first-name-consists-of-two-words) for a discussion of the (non-programming-related) problems that this can cause.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel For the situation you mentioned, I think using the name Jean-Paul as the first name may be better, like Jean-Paul Doe. Using John Paul Doe might make it easier for people to mistake 'John' as the first name, 'Paul' as the middle name, and 'Doe' as the last name.

Comment: @Whozcry: Yes, writing "John-Paul" instead of "John Paul" would certainly make it clearer that both words belong to the first name. However, as mentioned in the [link that I posted in my previous comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78746/how-to-get-others-to-understand-that-my-first-name-consists-of-two-words), some people want to be addressed by their actual first name and don't want the space in their first name to be changed to a hyphen.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It's hard to please everyone.  For some people, in the format of "John Paul Doe", "John" is considered as the first name, while for others, "John Paul" is considered as the first name. In case of such situations, what should the program output as the first name?

Comment: @Whozcry: If the program has a list of all known double names, then if the program finds a match of one of the double names, it could assume that the matched characters actually do represent a double name. However, I am not sure if such an assumption is reliable. For example, I am not sure if it is legally possible for someone to have "John" as the first name and "Paul" as the middle name. My guess is that it is possible, because the laws regarding names are rather liberal in some countries. :)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Based on the question he asked and the related code provided, I believe he wants to express that the first name only has one word, which is also a convention. I think the focus should be on where the input word is stored and how to print it out.

Comment: @Whozcry: In contrast to the example that you provided in one of your previous comments, in which the input "Paul" could also represent a middle name, in the case of OP's code, the user is only supposed to enter a "first name". For this reason, there cannot be any ambiguity in the input. Therefore, I see no reason to limit the input to a single word. That way, the program can handle both single names and double names properly. However, I do not want to criticize your answer too much, because it is already 99,5% correct. As far as I am concerned, you can keep it as-is.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Forgive me as a non-native English speaker, I didn't know about the question you were talking about("it is possible for a first name to consist of several words") **before**. Now I add a new other solution, but I think the new method I added is not particularly related to the original problem. However, it can indeed solve the problem you mentioned. How do you feel about my answer now?

Comment: @Whozcry: Yes, your answer now also works with double names. That is good. However, your answer was already quite good beforehand. This was only a minor issue. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote your answer more than once.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you for your feedback. Hearing you say "That is good" means a lot to me, and it makes me feel that my answer is now truly qualified.

Answer (score 2):

Using `scanf` with the `%c` conversion format specifier will only read a single character.

In order to read a whole word, you can use the `%s` specifier instead. However, in the English langauge, it is possible for a first name to consist of several words, such as [John Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Paul_(given_name)). In that case, "Paul" is not a middle name, but part of the first name. With the input `"John Paul"`, `scanf` would only read `"John"` from the input stream and leave `" Paul"` on the input stream. This would probably be undesirable.

For this reason, it would probably be better to read and store a whole line of input, instead of only a single word. Although this is also possible with `scanf`, I recommend to use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

When reading in a string consisting of several characters, you must provide a pointer to a memory location that has sufficient allocated space for storing the string. Providing a pointer to a single `char` is not sufficient, as such a memory location is only able to store a single character. This means that the memory location is only able to store an empty string consisting only of a null terminating character.

One simple way of allocating sufficient space for storing a string is to declare a `char` array. When passing such an array to a function, the array will automatically [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char first_name[200];

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Enter your name: " );

    //read one line of input
    if ( fgets( first_name, sizeof first_name, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //remove newline character from the input, if it exists,
    //by overwriting it with a null terminating character
    first_name[strcspn(first_name,"\n")] = '\0';

    //print back input to user
    printf( "Hello, %s.\n", first_name );
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Enter your name: John Paul
Hello, John Paul.
```